# How to sign out of google chrome browser and remove google toolbar?

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome

It use to be nice and one can sign out of google chrome account and it will clean up all personalization like remove the toolbar etc but not anymore! It's not easy to signout completely but now you can pause synronization.

If I a manage to signout, the toolbar, books all stay!

What is the way to reset google chrome, remove toolbars, books, everything when I log out?

Answer (score -1):

There is no way! Uninstall google chrome from control panel!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/810349)

Comment: @Ramhound I looked into it a lot on how to uninstall it. There is actually no other way to get rid of them. It is to help people save time. If anyone post any other valid answer, I will delete this answer.